# How does spring resolve .jsp page without controller mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand the following issue. When I type url http://localhost:8076/demoproject_war/test.jsp spring is able to load test.jsp page. Here is the pic of my directory structure.
[image: my dir structure]

My question is how spring loads ./test.jsp even though I don't have any mappings in my controller class for ./test.jsp . Does not this request go to controller to check the mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not load this JSP when you go to that URL. You're navigating directly to the JSP. It is considered a bad practice as you're not controlling the execution in this case. You should put the JSPs inside a `webapp/WEB-INF` directory. Then, the won't be accessible directly.

Comment: Thanks @madhead for response. when I type for example http://localhost:8076/demoproject_war/login it goes to spring controller to check the mappings , but in case of test.jsp it goes directly to the folder. So how spring differentiates when to use controller mapping and when to go to directory? if it sees that resource ends with .jsp it goes to directory otherwise to controller , or how?